# Can I make the array modifier work on global coordinates?

Tags: modifiers

I believe the array modifier uses local coordinates to the object being replicated.

I have a cube I want replicated and I would like to get

[image]

but what I always get is

[image]

I have set Transform Orientations for the object to global but to no avail.

As usual, any help appreciated...

TIA

Comment: If you ask this question I suppose that it's because you don't want to change the orientation of your object in Edit mode? Just to make sure...   ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Modifiers work on the mesh.**

The orientation of the default cube is "logical".  With (0, 0, 0) rotation it sits *"flat"*.  It all makes sense. Start to rotate in edit mode (or in object mode and apply) it all starts getting a bit hard to follow.

Modifiers work on the mesh (data) part of an object.  A couple of ways to change the orientation of the mesh before using the array modifier.

**1. Armature Modfifier before the array modifier.**

If the armature modifier rotates the mesh before the array this'll work.

[image]
*Rotating the bone, and result on cube 16 x 16 array*

Here I've added a single bone middle of default cube, selected cube, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> selected bone, <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> set parent,  and chosen automatic weights. Now rotating the pose bone rotates the cube. If the armature modifier is before the array modifier it will do what you want, ie rotate each cube in the array.

[image]

**Shape keys**

Keep the normal orientation of cube as the Basis key.  Add a shape key(s) for the rotated state(s).  Because shape-keys are moving the vertices (data) of the mesh, this will give desired result too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that array will do what I want if only I go into edit mode. I had been in object mode...

Sorry to have asked a little hastily.